# Bat file to to run a group of text files in sequence

Tags: batch-file

I am new here and I am having a bit of trouble obtaining my desired output.

I have a locked down system with no Powershell etc and I need to manipulate some txt files in a certain order.  I have looked at doing this with excel VBA, however the time it takes to output renders this unrealistic.

I am looking to create a BAT file to complete the object via CMD.

I need it to (in this order):-

1. Change the filenames to "FILE" & 1, then 2 then 3 etc.
2. Replace all spaces with commas in the content of the text files.
3. Remove all underscores from the content of the text files.
4. Remove all Alpha text characters (A-Z) from the content of the text files.
5. Remove any blank lines from the text files.
6. Merge all text files with the filenames on EACH line of the text to for example 'output.tmp'.

I have had some luck achieving this with separate bat files however I am having trouble with points 1,3 and 4.

I would also like to at some stage be able to remove any numbers which are not between two separate values eg 1 and 3 and 6 and 9.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The complexity of your question gives me the impression that Excel VBA macros are indeed a good technological choice. Batchfiles are in general not that good manipulating the content of files. Therefore I would advise you to seek for optimising your VBA instead of choosing other technology. http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a good site for optimisation questions.

Comment: VBA ?? Piece od crap ;-) Windows ? You can use way easier JavaScript (similar to web except files, etc.) - just run or use cscript/wscript, quite similar J# or C# - csc.exe compiler is often already part of .NET - all you have to do write your.cs file, (find and) run csc.exe your.cs and run compiled exe. In case of linux there is often Node.js option - default in most containers at least, again JS, but no restrictions. In case of some UI need also HTA could ve option (old JS + HTML).

Comment: https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools some examples in CSharp or HTM_HTA